# How to avoid unwanted hits on MSSQL Database Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008

i have MSSQL Database server, Daily am getting more than 50,000 unwanted login attempts for sa user. because this server got low performance. how to avoid this

i have disabled sa user instead of that i have create new sql admin user. but when i have check sql log same issue invalid user & password login attempts.

please help me anyone to resolve this issue.

Comment: Sometimes SQL Service CPU Utilization goes more than 80%

Comment: you mean you have login for `sa` enabled on a public sql server? it is like saying "Welcome hackers"

Comment: i have disabled sa user, even though same issue

Comment: allow access only from your IP ie.. access only for your application

Comment: Can you explain briefly why do you need an exposed instance of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

1/ Switch from using "mixed mode" authentication to windows accounts.

2/ If (and only if) an external service requires access to the SQL Server, permit access to the [specific IP addresses](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2006/04/10/572605.aspx) required at the firewall.

3/ Put in place a VPN Network between the office and the data center.

4/ Persist IPs where those request comes from than ignore any request coming from those IPs. Check with your hosting provider if they offer any "IP deny" feature.

Comment: am not getting hits from any of application, its direct server hit

Comment: i have my own dedicated server

Comment: am the hosting provider i have own dedicated server.